# WebAPI 404 for a bad url

Tags: .net, iis, webapi

A survey went out to an email audience with the incorrect url:

[www.my-url.com/%C2%A0](http://www.my-url.com/%C2%A0)

(I'm omitting the real url, but the problem is the /%C2%A0 at the end.) Since it has gone out what I want to do is to modify the web site to return the correct page. However, I can't seem to make it work. It is a WebAPI site returning ContentResult. So for example I tried this:

```
      [HttpGet]
      [Route("%C2%A0")]
      public async Task<ContentResult> Get(string s)
```

Which didn't work, I also tried [Route("{s}")] which also didn't work.

There is also a controller with this signature:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ContentResult> Get()
```

Which is why I have the s parameter to distinguish.

Then I tried to set the 404 page in IIS to redirect to the correct page (visiting the url gives a 404) but that also didn't work -- it, along with all the other things I tried, continued with 404.

Since this is a WebAPI I wonder if there is some special consideration I am not taking into account, or if you have any suggestions.

Using .net 6.

Comment: Or use IIS URL Rewrite to rewrite that (`/%C2%A0`) URL to `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a little tricky.

```
[HttpGet]
//[Route("%C2%A0")]            // Ends up needing /%25C2%25A0
//[Route("{s:minlength(6)}")]  // Doesn't work for special chars
[Route("{6}")]                 // A regex does the trick
public IActionResult Get(string s = "hi")
{
    return Ok("hi");
}


[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok("hi1");
}
```